# ASP.NET MVC Referencing Html Helper from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've written an Html Helper called DetailsForm to reduce repetition when displaying fields in a view.  Within a view  -  actually a partial view, ascx file  -  I can refer to it like this:

```
Storyboard.Helpers.DetailsForm.LabelAndData(Html, m => m.id)
```

But would like to refer to it like this:

```
LabelAndData(Html, m => m.id)
```

A 'using' directive doesn't seem to be allowed in the ascx file.  Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to import the namespace in the top of your ascx, like so:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Storyboard.Helpers" %>
```

**UPDATE**

Reading your comment, I'm guessing your helper looks something like:

```
public static Something LabelAndData(this HtmlHelper html, .....
```

in which case you would call it like this in your view:

```
Html.LabelAndData(m => m.id)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I get "A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Storyboard.Helpers.DetailsForm' is a type not a namespace"

Comment: So I tried using just Storyboard.Helpers but then it goes back to complaining that "The name 'LabelAndData' does not eixst in the current context".

Comment: If this still doesn't help, it would be helpful if you post the code to your helper, including namespace and class..

Comment: Yes, that works.  I couldn't refer to it properly as an extension to Html before, hence the passing it as the first parameter, but now it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use the same namespace as the Default Html Helpers which is `System.Web.Mvc.Html` of MVC for the one that you created, you don't need to reference your created Html Helper anywhere.